# Не стартует Apache под XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp

При попытке запустить Апач из СР XAMPP не получаю никаких ошибок.

```
23:28:43  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache service...
23:28:43  [Apache]  Executing "net start "Apache2.4""
23:28:46  [Apache]  Return code: 0
```

В службах висит апач 2.4, вручную отказывается стартовать, авто при ребуте - тоже;
порты проверял и менял. Где искать корень проблемы? Заранее спасибо за советы!

з.ы. В системе есть денвер, неактивный. Не знаю, насколько он может влиять и может ли вообще.

Comment: неактивный денвер вряд ли может повлиять, а вот включенный Skype может, т.к. и Apache и Skype используют 80 порт, если действительно есть включенный скайп, то в настройках скайпа необходимо запретить использование портов 80/433 (галочка в настройках)